# create a nested list in python

Tags: python, tree, nested-lists

I have a tree based on the picture below. I would like to write a function creating a nested list according to the picture using python.
The following is what I have tried, but it is wrong. Could anyone help please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKvrV.png)

```
def treepic (obj, x):    
    x=[]
    x.append(obj.split)
    
    if obj.lhs.is_leaf==False:
        x.append([])
        return treepic(obj.lhs,x[1])    #lhs:left child of the current node   
    else:
        x.append(obj.lhs.split)
        
    if obj.lhs.is_leaf==False:
        x.append([])
        return treepic(obj.rhs,x[2])    #rhs:right child of the current node      
    else:
        x.append(obj.rhs.split)     
    return x
```

Comment: `obj` appears to be an instance of some sort of tree class; can you provide that class's definition?

Comment: the code is going to be super long.  Let's say the class Tree. This class has 4 attributes: split, is_leaf,lhs, rhs. Then lhs,rhs are also objects of this class Tree. until obj.is_leaf =True.